# Rails 5 belongs_to namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespace

Tenho o seguinte configuração

```
module  Account
  class Permission < ApplicationRecord
  end
end

module Account
  class GroupPermission < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :permission
  end
end

Table:  account_permissions
           name character varying

Table:  account_group_permissions
       account_permissions_id bigint,
      account_groups_id bigint,
```

Quando tento acessar  a instancia Account::GroupPermission  e por ela acessar Account::Permission  retorna nil.

Só funciona se eu especificar o class_name:

Answer (score 0):

Não é comum, em Rails, colocar models dentro de modules, como você fez nos seus models com o module `Account`.

Sendo assim, o Rails não consegue achar a classe da associação automaticamente, por isso só funciona especificando um `class_name`.

```
belongs_to :permission, class_name: "Account::Permission"
```

Eu te aconselho a remover os módulos, visto que o Rails segue [convenções sobre configurações](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conven%C3%A7%C3%A3o_sobre_configura%C3%A7%C3%A3o). Isso quer dizer que pode ser que você tenha mais problemas depois.